# EF CF: complex types for legacy database

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1

I successfully mapped my complex type like this:

```
modelBuilder
     .ComplexType<Name>()
     .Property(name => name.First)
     .HasColumnName("firstNameColumn");

modelBuilder
     .ComplexType<Name>()
     .Property(name => name.Last)
     .HasColumnName("lastNameColumn");
```

So far so good. But notice that we do not specify any entity type. What if we want to map the same complext type also for a table with columns "firstN" and "lastN"? I tried EntityTypeConfiguration<> but you are not allowed to specify complex types there. Finally it looks like that complexTypes are defined globally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also customize the complex type columns names at the entity level, like the following:

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public Name NameInfo { get; set; }
}

public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public Name NameInfo { get; set; }
}

[ComplexType]
public class Name
{
    public string First { get; set; }
    public string Last { get; set; }
}

public class Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.ComplexType<Name>()
                    .Property(name => name.First)
                    .HasColumnName("firstNameColumn");

        modelBuilder.ComplexType<Name>()
                    .Property(name => name.Last)
                    .HasColumnName("lastNameColumn");

        // Here is how can customize the column names at the entity level:
        modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().Property(u => u.NameInfo.First)
                                       .HasColumnName("firstN");

        modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().Property(u => u.NameInfo.Last)
                                       .HasColumnName("lastN");
    }
}
```

And the resultant schema will be:

[image]

**[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5322068/entity-framework-4-custom-complex-type-mapping/5328253#5328253)** you can find another example.